# Run JavaScript code after loading and executing an external script

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, html

I would like to dynamically load and execute a 3rd party JavaScript file (from a different domain) and then execute some of my own code after that is done. I could use jQuery's `$.getScript`:

```
$.getScript('https://login.persona.org/include.js', function () {
    // my code
});
```

but, according to the jQuery documentation, there is no guarantee that the script has executed by the time the callback is invoked.

What are my options here? I need the most basic solution for one-time use.

Comment: what is your jquery version? did you try on `$.getScript( "xx.js" )
  .done(function( script, textStatus ) {})
  .fail(function( jqxhr, settings, exception ) {});` to make sure it complete load.

Comment: @CheongBC How can I make sure that the script has executed? As I said in my question, the `.done()` callback is not guaranteed to run after the script has executed.

Answer (score 0):

Updated

Try

```js
console.log("navigatorId:", navigator.id);

$(window).queue("login", Array(
    function(next) {
      return $.getScript("https://login.persona.org/include.js").then(next)
    }
  , function() {
       console.log("navigatorId:", navigator.id)  
    }
)).dequeue("login");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```

See [.queue()](http://api.jquery.com/queue/)

Comment: If `textStatus === 'success'`, does that guarantee that the script has executed?

Answer (score -1):

You can try to add a small timeout to your callback to ensure the script file has executed. For example

```
$.getScript('https://login.persona.org/include.js', function () {
    setTimeout(function(){
        // my code
    }, 25);
});
```

Comment: And hope to god the device isn't running slow? No thanks.